# Is there any practical difference between the FFT and the inverse FFT?

Tags: fft, fftw

FFT libraries such as FFTW or numpy.fft typically provide two functions `fft()` and `ifft()` (and special versions thereof for real valued input). Those functions appear to be defined such that

```
ifft(fft(X)) == X
```

and

```
fft(X) == constant_factor * reverse(ifft(X))
```

Are there any practical or technical reasons to consider when choosing between `ifft()` and `fft()` operating on complex input? While the interpretations of `X` (signal, time or space domain) and `fft(X)` (spectrum, frequency domain) are different, does it ever matter computationally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different fft libraries put the scaling constant in different places, in the fft, ifft or 1/sqrt(N) in both.  So that's only a minor implementation dependent difference.  The fft and the ifft reverse the order of their results.  So that's only a difference between indexing forwards or backwards in you result array.  Whether you call one time/space versus frequency is only a labeling difference.

So practically, pick the one where whatever scale the library uses and the direction you want to index your results produces the most readable code.  Usually the fft/ifft libraries are set up so that one can index positive time and higher frequency in the same direction (++).

ADDED: Minor, probably unnecessary optimization: if you need to post-scale the FT results anyway, then pick the fft or ifft implementation that doesn't include a built-in scale multiply, as this may save N semi-redundant multiply operations.

Comment: Aren't the twiddle factors different for forward/inverse FFT ? From memory I think the sign changes on the imaginary part ?

Comment: Changing the signs in some twiddle factors is what "reverses time" or outputs a result vector with the opposite indexing direction.

Comment: OK - thanks - I'd never really considered the possibility that the FFT and IFFT might be interchangeable in this way - I'll have to look into this further, if only for curiosity's sake.

Comment: so technically, if the fft was implemented with 1/sqrt(N), then `fft(fft(array))` would return the reverse array? Correct me if im wrong

Comment: fft(fft()) would reverse the array, usually symmetric around element 0, possible scaled, depending on implementation scaling, possibly including numerical rounding noise.  Symmetry: the value in array element 0 should stay the same, depending on indexing (C vs. matlab, etc.).